# Mysterious SCRIPT18 error in IE developer console

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

We are getting SCRIPT18 errors in IE 11 like this:

[image]

These errors do not happen in Chrome or Edge.

Google has not turned up anything useful; in fact, there are very few links that even reference the error (I think SCRIPT18 might be a hard term for google to index).

Here is the code:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById(R_TABLE_NAME);
if(tbl == null){tbl = test.document.getElementById(R_TABLE_NAME);}
for (var i=0; i<tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
// following line is 131:
    if (tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow && tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.five.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox' && tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.five.checked) {
        checkedObjArray[cCount] = tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i];
        cCount++;
        cRow = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

This is an internal-only web app so I can tell the users they need to use edge or chrome but that is not a very good solution for me right now as we have other web apps that still require IE.

Plus, I treat an error on one browser as an error on all browsers as I have found that sometimes an explicit error in one browser is a hidden error in a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible that you have faulty condition or your condition is not returning expected value causing this error in line below.

```
 if (tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow && tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.five.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox' && tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.five.checked) {
```

I suggest you to try to use console.log() to see which value is returned by each condition. It can help to find the faulty condition in the code.

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("R_TABLE_NAME");

for (var i=0; i < tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
// following line is 131:
    console.log("con-1 " + tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow);
    console.log("con-2 " + tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.five.getAttribute('type'));
    console.log("con-3 " + tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.five.checked);
    if (tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow && tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.five.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox' && tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.five.checked) {
        console.log("Hello...");
    }
}
```

If you find that any condition is not returning the expected value than try to check in your code whether you had properly set it or not. If you did not set that properly than it can cause this issue here.

For testing purpose, try to replace the conditions with any simple conditions or try to test all conditions one by one to check whether it helps to solve the error or not. If it solves it than you need to revised your conditions to solve this issue.

If issue persist than you can try to post the code where you assign those rows values. We will try to make a test with it.

Comment: The error went away when we added the console.log statements.  That indicates to me that this is a race condition with a popup window.  The developer is doing code analysis with that in mind.  I will post back what we learn.

Comment: status update: We left the console.log statements in the code to get around the issue for now. We will make another pass at a solution later and will post it when we figure it out.